# clickonce app.publish\setup.exe have a wrong modified date in the past

Tags: clickonce, publish, bootstrapper, setup.exe

I have an error when trying to publish a WPF application  on VS2010 ultimate with clickonce:
error MSB3169: An error occurred generating a bootstrapper: Unable to begin updating resource for bin\Debug\app.publish\setup.exe

I notice that my app.publish\setup.exe have a wrong modified date in the past
the creation date is : 5-05-2013, 14:47:07
the modifed date is : 18-04-2010, 04:21:40
I thing this is very weird...

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Try publishing through the Build menu instead of using the Publish button on the screen. This may be caused by a race condition.

Another thing I've seen recommended is to do a repair on Visual Studio; this could be a problem with the setup.bin file being corrupted.

Comment: I tried your two options but they doesn't work for me .Thanks

Answer (score 1):

On vs2010 
Go to tools->import and Export Settings then click on Reset all settings.
This solve my problem

You can also use publish button from the top menu : Build->publish